# Verify data in a sqlite database hasn't been modified by anyone else (i.e sign the data)

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using a SqlLite database, and I would like to ensure that the data has not been modified outside the application. (sign the data)

Does sqlite keep a last modified date of the data?

I was thinking about using the Windows last modified file date, but that is my second choice. I was hoping sqlite would have a way to tell me either a hash of the data or a timestamp of the last data modified.

One option is to calculate a hash of all the contents of the bytes of the database file, this would allow me to guarantee that the file hasn't been modified by anyone. But this is expensive and I am hoping to find a better way to verify no external sources modified the database.

Another option is to encrypt the database, but this is not ideal because we want 3rd parties to be able to read the data, just not to modify it.

Note that I am accessing the database using System.Data.Sqlite in a WPF .net client application on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much you can do about it. In the first line of defense you can put some triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_ins_on_table1 BEFORE INSERT ON table1
BEGIN SELECT RAISE( FAIL, 'Not allowed.' ) ; END;

CREATE TRIGGER before_del_on_table1 BEFORE DELETE ON table1
BEGIN SELECT RAISE( FAIL, 'Not allowed.' ) ; END;

CREATE TRIGGER before_upd_on_table1 BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
BEGIN SELECT RAISE( FAIL, 'Not allowed.' ) ; END;
```

but...

You can digitally sign the database or embed a SHA1 hash in your program and make it refuse to use the database if the hashes doesn't match, but this is generally useless.

To put it simply, if the database is readable, there's nothing you can do to stop someone who is motivated enough to tamper it. The attacker can simply dump and then restore the data in a new database without restrictions.